# Renaming Pandas DataFrame columns that are numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that has integers for column names that looks like this:

```
      1     2     3     4
 Red  7     3     2     9
 Blue 3     1     6     4
```

I'd like to rename the columns. I tried using the following

```py
df = df.rename(columns={'1': 'One', '2': 'Two', '3': 'Three', '4': 'Four'})
```

However that doesn't change the column names. Do I need to do something else to change column names when they are numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the quotes:

```py
df = df.rename(columns={1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three', 4: 'Four'})
```

Comment: I approve this message (-:  Also a bit cheeky `df.rename(columns='Zero One Two Three Four'.split().__getitem__)`

Answer (score 1):

What if you use the following:

```
>>> df.columns = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
>>> df
    One Two Three   Four
0   7   3   6       9
1   3   1   2       4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two way to change columns name in Pandas DataFrame.

1. Changing the column name using df.columns attribute.

   `df.columns = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']`
2. Using rename() function

   `df = df.rename(columns={1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three', 4: 'Four'})`